# Unix command that immediately returns a particular return code?

Tags: shell, command-line, exit-status

Is there a standard Unix command that does something similar to my example below

```
$ <cmd here> 56
$ echo Return code was $?
Return code was 56
$
```

`<cmd here>` should be something that can be fork-execed and leaves 56 as the exit code when the process exits. The `exit` and `return` shell builtins are unsuitable for what I'm looking for because they affect the invoking shell itself by exiting out of it. `<some cmd>` should be something that I can execute in non-shell contexts - e.g., invoking from a Python script with `subprocess`.

E.g., `/usr/bin/false` always exits immediately with return code 1, but I'd like to control exactly what that return code is. I could achieve the same results by writing my own wrapper script

```
$ cat my-wrapper-script.sh # i.e., <some cmd> = ./my-wrapper-script.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
exit $1
$ ./my-wrapper-script.sh 56
$ echo $?
56
```

but I'm hoping there happens to exist a standard Unix command that can do this for me.

Comment: `exit` is the only one I can think of, but it tends to end your shell.  `bash -c 'exit 56'` or `bash -c "exit $1"` might work for you.

Comment: @TimKennedy seems to have guessed what my poorly spec-ed out question was trying to ask and answered it. `bash -c 'exit 56'` does what I'd like to do!

Comment: How about `(exit 56)`?

Comment: `$python -c 'import sys;sys.exit(int(sys.argv[1]))' 56;
$echo $? -> 56` works.

Comment: This really sounds like a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) : what is the ultimate goal of this? Why do you need a command that returns as exit code the number you give it?

Comment: if you need this for job control, for example, you can usually change `any command` into `{ any command ; exit 56 ; }`   (or `return 56`, if you don't want to exit the engobing shell)

Comment: Just for the record, here is the [dual question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110767/unix-utility-which-executes-a-command-and-tests-its-exit-status)

Comment: Well, you have the `true` and `false` built-ins if you need to return 0 or 1.

Comment: or `\`exit 56\``.

Comment: related: (non portable) smallest program to return a compile-time fixed value:
http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Answer (score 47):

1. A `return` based function would work, and avoids the need to open and close another shell, (as per [*Tim Kennedy*'s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315365/unix-command-that-immediately-returns-a-particular-return-code/315368#comment554283_315365)):

   ```
   freturn() { return "$1" ; } 
   freturn 56 ; echo $?
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   56
   ```
2. using `exit` in a subshell:

   ```
   (exit 56)
   ```

   With shells other than `ksh93`, that  implies forking an extra process so is less efficient than the above.
3. `bash`/`zsh`/`ksh93` only trick:

   ```
   . <( echo return 56 )
   ```

   (that also implies an extra process (and IPC with a pipe)).
4. `zsh`'s lambda functions:

   ```
   (){return 56}
   ```

Comment: Good thought. Unfortunately, my original question was not defined well enough - needing to "open and close another shell" was almost a requirement of what I wanted to do. I edited my question to require that `<some cmd>` is an execve()-able thing.

Comment: @Chris: For any shell command you can make it execve()able by converting it to `/bin/sh -c ...originalcommand...`

Comment: I am mildly disappointed that ?=56 doesn't work.

Comment: @Joshua: maybe it does? but then this affectation was successful, and you have $? set to 0 ... ;)

Comment: @OlivierDulac: It doesn't. It spits out a parse error.

Comment: @joshua: i was just joking to point out that even if it did work, it wouldnt set $? to the value 56 ^^

Answer (score 18):

There is no standard UNIX command for just returning a specific value. The GNU Core Utilies provide `true` and `false` only.

However, you can easily implement this yourself as `ret`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  return argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
cc ret.c -o ret
```

And run:

```
./ret 56 ; echo $?
```

Prints:

```
56
```

---

If you need this to work everywhere (where bash is available, that is) without installing any extra tools, you probably need to resort to the following command as @TimKennedy suggested in comments:

```
bash -c 'exit 56'
```

---

Note that the [valid range of return values is 0..255 inclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082953/what-is-the-valid-range-for-program-return-value-in-linux-bash).

Comment: `true` and `false` are in Unix (and even POSIX) as well, not only in GNU.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for pointing that out. As the OP mentioned bash, I somehow assumed GNU -- even though the question itself states 'Unix'.

Answer (score 14):

If you need the exit status to be set by an executed commands. There is no dedicated command for that<sup>1</sup>, but you can use the interpreter of any language that has the capability to exit with an arbitrary exit status. `sh` is the most obvious one:

```
sh -c 'exit 56'
```

With most `sh` implementations, that's limited to exit codes 0 to 255 (`sh` will accept greater values but may truncate it or even cause a signal to be sent to the process executing `sh` like with ksh93 for codes 257 to 320).

An exit code can be any integer (`int`) value but note that you need to retrieve it with the `waitid()` interface so the value is not truncated to 8 bits (on Linux, it's still truncated with `waitid()` as well though). Hence why it's rare (and not a good idea) to use exit codes above 255 (use 0-123 for normal operation).

Alternatively:

```
awk 'BEGIN{exit 56}'
perl -e 'exit 56'
python -c 'exit(56)'
expect -c 'exit 56'
```

(those don't truncate the exit code to 8 bits).

With NetBSD `find`, you can do:

```
find / -exit 56
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>`exit` is the standard command to do that but being a shell *special builtin*, there's no requirement that there also be a command by that name in the file system like for regular built-ins, and most systems won't include one</sub>

Answer (score 3):

```
/* Public domain, http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/ */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    if(!strcasecmp(argv[0],"true")) return 0;
    else if (!strcasecmp(argv[0],"false")) return 1;
    else if(argc<2) {fputs("One argument required\n",stderr);return 1;}
    else if(!strcasecmp(argv[argc-1],"true")) return 0;
    else if(!strcasecmp(argv[argc-1],"false")) return 1;
    else return atoi(argv[argc-1]);
}
```

Save this in a file named `returncode.c` and `gcc -o returncode returncode.c`

Comment: On a semi-related note: 1) applying the CC0 license without naming yourself as an affirmer is probably not a good idea, and you should do it [like this](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F), 2) programs this small are too trivial for your copyright to matter, so you might as well leave out the license.

Comment: (1) I don’t understand why you’re using `argv[argc-1]` instead of `argv[1]`, and why you’re not complaining if `argc>2`. (2) I’d be inclined to do the `argv[1]` test before the `argv[0]` test, allowing the user to say `true 56` or `false 56` instead of `returncode 56`. You don’t give a message if `argv[0]` is a word and `argc>0` — that could be confusing. (3) I’m obsessed with user-friendliness, so I’d use `strcasecmp` instead of `strcmp`. (4) I tend to validate parameters, and not use the return value of `atoi` without verifying it. For a 2¢ program like this, I guess it doesn’t matter.

Comment: @G-Man Neither `true` nor `false` processes any argument in Linux systems

Comment: OK, that’s correct — they don’t processes any argument, including `argv[0]`; the programs `/bin/true` and `/bin/false` are different executables, with hard-coded exit codes. You’ve written a program that can be installed as ***both*** `true` and `false` (linked), which is clever. But the question asks how to get a user-specified exit status. Your program answers that question, but only if it is installed under a different filename. As long as you’re looking at `argv` anyway, I believe that doing it the way I suggest would maintain the level of cleverness, by avoiding the need for a third link.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't exactly sure if your only problem with the `exit` command was it exiting out of the current shell, but if so, a subshell might work.

```
username@host$ $(exit 42)
username@host$ echo $?
42
```

I tested this on Cygwin Bash just now and it works for me.

Edit: Sorry I missed the part of running it outside a shell context. In that case thsi wouldn't help without wrapping it within a `.sh` script and executing that from your environment.

Comment: `$(exit 42)` tries to execute the output of `exit 42` as a simple command which makes little sense (it also wouldn't work with `yash`). `(exit 42)` (also run `exit` in a subshell, but leaves its output alone) would make more sense and would be more portable (even to csh or the Bourne shell).